# How to connect with JSch through proxy?

Tags: java, proxy, sftp, firewall, jsch

I am connecting to a remote `sftp` using the `jsch` library

```
  JSch jsch = new JSch();       
  Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, Integer.parseInt(port) ); 
  session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");   
  session.setPassword(password); 
  session.connect(); 
  System.out.println("The session has been established");
```

Everything works great on my home computer. However, whenever I use my work computer, it throws an error: `unknown host`. This is because my work computer is set to redirect any request to a proxy server . I tried to overcome this issue by adding this line

```
  String proxy_host = "xxx . . . proxy . . . companyname.com"; 
  int proxy_port = 8080; 
  session.setProxy(new ProxySOCKS5(proxy_host, proxy_port));
```

But then I get a refused connection error. I also tried port forwarding, but it didn't work. How to connect to a remote sftp ?

Comment: 1) Firewall and proxy are two different things. I assume your real question is *"How to connect with JSch through proxy?"* 2) Are you able to connect with any (even GUI) SSH/SFTP client?

Comment: Thank you i corrected my question. i haven't tried any GUI.

Comment: So do try. That's a key information. If you cannot connect using any existing client, you will hardly be able to code it yourself. Your company firewall may be blocking the connection.

Comment: So yes. I was able to connect. There must be a way for me to do the same programmatically

Comment: What client did you use? Can you show us its log file? If you want our help, make sure you share all information you have. Do not wait for us to ask for it.